# VB.NET: type initializer for color structure throws an exception

Tags: vb.net

this sub throws an "type initializer" exception on a few machines (maybe 1 in a thousand) and I have absolutely no clue why:

```
Public Sub init_colors()
    For i As Int32 = 0 To 100            
        colors(i) = Color.FromArgb(255, setup.color1.R * i / 100 + setup.color2.R * (1 - i / 100), setup.color1.G * i / 100 + setup.color2.G * (1 - i / 100), setup.color1.B * i / 100 + setup.color2.B * (1 - i / 100))            
    Next        
End Sub
```

colors() is a public array defined by

```
  Public farben(0 To 100) As Color
```

And the sub creates a color gradient specified by class "setup" and its members color1 and color2 which are both color structures.

I've tried to add

```
farben(i) = new color
```

but as expected this does not help

Thanks

Christian

Comment: actually what you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: `Color.FromArgb` accepts integer arguments, you are passing doubles. Since it compiles i suggest to use `OPTION STRICT On`. Then you could use \ instead of / to fix the compiler error which is integer division and truncates decimal places.

Comment: It creates a color table to save time later in the program. I don't think the type cast is the problem when an "type initializer" exception is thrown. Maybe it has something to do with the alpha channel that may not be supported on some machines?